# Why do some car fan resistor modules have both a wirewound resistor and another component?

Tags: resistors, automotive

I'm reusing/salvaging a car radiator fan and fan resistor module (for a non-car related project), and wondered: why does the resistor module have both a wirewound resistor and another component? (Perhaps this other component is also a resistor?)

As I understand it, the resistor is connected to a relay which is only triggered when the engine is off, operating the fan in "slow mode". I imagine that if they are both resistors, perhaps either one is used as a backup, but I could be way off. If the smaller component is not a resistor, perhaps it's a fuse?

When using the resistor module, is it important which direction the current flows? There doesn't appear to be a positive and negative label. For instance, should the current flow first through the wirewound resistor, or through the other component?

The wirewound resistor has "R48K" printed on it, and the other component I'm not sure about (maybe it's also a resistor, or perhaps it's some sort of fuse). The module is called a "Fiat 500 PA66 Radiator Fan Resistor Pack".

**Edit:** The unidentified component appears to be wired in series, and when I increase the heat, the resistance increases. So, I guess it's a thermal resistor of some kind.

[image: Fiat 500 PA66 Radiator Fan Resistor Pack]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks a lot like a thermal fuse. it will go open circuit if it gets too hot.

[image: thermal fuse]

It's most-likely purpose is to prevent the resistor from starting a fire if the fan motor is jammed.

With a series connection all the current flows through both parts, and as these parts are both non-polarised the direction that the current flows is not important.

Answer (score 2):

It could well be a thermal switch - if the resistor gets too hot it opens the circuit. Check to see if it is in series or parallel.

Comment: It's wired in series, and when I increase the heat, the resistance increases. So, I guess it's a thermal resistor of some kind.

Comment: Sounds like a PTC thermistor.  If this was for temperature control, usually one would use an NTC instead (to increase fan speed as temperature rises).  The PTC may be used to limit the fan current under certain conditions.   What do you read for resistance across each component at room temperature?

Comment: The "resistor pack" module is advertised at 0.8 Ω. I'm measuring about 0.6 Ω on the actual wirewound resistor, and about 0.2 Ω from the thermistor. As soon as I heat the element up, resistance increases to several MΩ... it climbs up to 60 MΩ then the multimeter stops displaying a reading. So, it seems like it's designed to reduce current when the wirewound resistor gets hot. I can't think why. Here's the wiring diagram if you can make sense of it: https://f01.justanswer.com/heavy_chevy_396/cb9fb152-e4a4-4c0d-84e0-fefedd5cd530_2013_Fiat_500_1.4L_Eng_VIN_H_Sport_cool_fan_wir.pdf

Comment: However, I attached a 20A 12V DC power supply to the fan via the resistor, and the resistor started smoking... perhaps this is because the resistor is normally housed right next to the fan which cools the resistor down?

Answer (score 1):

If the component is connected in parallel with the resistor then I would suspect that it's a noise suppression capacitor but its location is a little unusual.